# Response when someone search on NULL object

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying get a response from sql for SAP conversational AI. In the code below every thing is working fine, but if there is a null object then the code just stops.
I need the response if there is null object.

```
app.post('/packers', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body.nlp.source)
rand = random.number(1, 9)

let hp = req.body.nlp.source

let sql= `SELECT * FROM data where catname = 9 AND address LIKE '%${hp}%' `;
let query = db.query(sql, (err, result)=> {
if (err) throw err;
Shopname = result[rand].shopname;
Adress = result[rand].address;
Mobile = result[rand].mobile;
res.send({
replies: [{ type: 'text',
 content: `Name of shop is ${Shopname} and address is ${Adress} and mobile no is ${Mobile}`,
}],
conversation: {
memory: { key: 'value' }
}
})
})
})
```

Comment: What exactly is null? Result[rand] or a property of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Lodash [get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get)

```
// this can throw if nlp isn't defined 
let hp = req.body.nlp.source

// this doesn't throw
let hp = _.get(req, 'body.nlp.source', null)

// For this case it throws if result[rand] isn't defined
Shopname = result[rand].shopname

// you can solve like this
Shopname = result[rand] ? result[rand].shopname : null
```